# ruby, rspec, and json.erb: unit testing a JSON template

Tags: ruby, json, rspec, erb

I'm having some trouble unit testing some windy json.erb logic. The below ERB template builds the required JSON file:

Fig1:

```
"api": {
<% unless @GLANCE_IMAGE_API_WORKERS_NUM.nil? %>
  "workers": <%= @GLANCE_IMAGE_API_WORKERS_NUM %>
<% if @GLANCE_BACKEND == 'ceph' %>
  <% unless @GLANCE_IMAGE_API_WORKERS_NUM.to_s.empty? %>,<% end %>
  "default_store": "rbd"
<% end %>
<% if !@IMAGE_CACHE_MAX_SIZE.to_s.empty? %>
  <% unless @GLANCE_IMAGE_API_WORKERS_NUM.to_s.empty? && @GLANCE_BACKEND != 'ceph' %>,<% end %>
  "cache" : {
    "image_cache_max_size": <%= @IMAGE_CACHE_MAX_SIZE %>
  }
<% end %>
```

To build the JSON it adds trailing commas if and when they are required. For example, if glance_backend is set to 'ceph', a comma is required after `glance.image.api_workers` to allow for a following entry and make the JSON valid - example:

Fig 2.

```
 "api": {
          "workers": 8,
          "cache": {
            "image_cache_max_size": 10000000000
          }
        },
```

I'm trying to test all the potential scenarios for the logic in Fig 1. I believe them to be something like this (pseudo-code):

- if `image_cache_max_size != empty && glance_backend == 'ceph' && glance_image_api_workers == "not_empty"`, add the comma after default_store entry to allow for next item;
- if `image_cache_max_size != empty && glance_backend == 'ceph' && glance_image_api_workers == ""`, no trailing comma;
- if `image_cache_max_size != empty && glance_backend == 'not_ceph' && glance_image_api_workers == "not_empty"`, no trailing comma;
- if `image_cache_max_size != empty && glance_backend == 'ceph' && glance_image_api_workers == ""`, no trailing comma.

So far, my rspec logic looks like this - Fig3:

```
context 'comma appended to "glance.api.workers" in correct circumstances' do

    before do
      data_bag['IMAGE_CACHE_MAX_SIZE'] = 10000
      data_bag['GLUSTER_BACKEND'] = 'ceph'
      data_bag['GLUSTER_IMAGE_API_WORKERS'] = 'not_empty'
    end

    it 'sets default_store attributes' do
      expect(override_attr['openstack']['image']['api']['workers'])
        .to include(",")
    end

    before do
      data_bag['IMAGE_CACHE_MAX_SIZE'] = 10000
      data_bag['GLUSTER_BACKEND'] = 'local'
      data_bag['GLUSTER_IMAGE_API_WORKERS'] = ''
    end

    it 'sets default_store attributes' do
      expect(override_attr['openstack']['image']['api']['workers'])
        .to_not include(",")
    end

    before do
      data_bag['IMAGE_CACHE_MAX_SIZE'] = 10000
      data_bag['GLUSTER_BACKEND'] = 'local'
      data_bag['GLUSTER_IMAGE_API_WORKERS'] = 'not_empty'
    end

    it 'sets default_store attributes' do
      expect(override_attr['openstack']['image']['api']['workers'])
        .to_not include(",")
    end
  end
```

This may be the completely wrong way to go about this. Looking forward to hearing some suggestions. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest yo use [jbuilder gem](https://github.com/rails/jbuilder). It allows to build any valid JSON structures you'd like. This way will allow you do get rid of complicated erb logic.

To test it's validness you may use [json_spec](https://github.com/collectiveidea/json_spec).

Here is an example:

```
# example_controller.rb

def workers
  @GLANCE_IMAGE_API_WORKERS_NUM = 8
  @GLANCE_BACKEND = "ceph"
  @IMAGE_CACHE_MAX_SIZE = 10000000000
  @GLUSTER_BACKEND = "ceph"
end

# app/views/whatever.jbuilder

json.api do |json|
  json.workers @GLANCE_IMAGE_API_WORKERS_NUM if @GLANCE_IMAGE_API_WORKERS_NUM
  json.cache do |nest|
    nest.image_cache_max_size @IMAGE_CACHE_MAX_SIZE
  end
end
```

It will produce

```
{
    "api": {
        "workers": 8,
        "cache": {
            "image_cache_max_size": 10000000000
        }
    }
}
```

Please be noted I have no idea how is your controller works. If you'll provide more details, I'll do ny best to help you better.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Useful to know. Unfortunately, I'm stuck with the erb logic & need to write unit tests accordingly. Chef builds the JSON file using the ERB file. The pseudo-code above is how I understand the controller to work.